# 500 internal server error while trying to use the registration form

Tags: joomla

I am using the registration form that is already available in the user manager option in my website.

But once I click on the register button I get this message:

> Server error
>  The website encountered an error while retrieving
>   http://prachi.matrimony4me.in/index.php/sample-sites-2?task=registration.register.
>   It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly. Here are
>   some suggestions: Reload this webpage later. 
> HTTP Error 500 (Internal
>   Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the
>   server was attempting to fulfill the request.

Comment: 500 internal server error is a common error message and tells nothing. Something goes wrong in the registration form, it can be anything. Are you able to access Joomla server side log files?

Comment: i tried to register and it worked fine: http://prachi.matrimony4me.in/index.php/using-joomla/extensions/components/users-component/registration-form

Answer (score 0):

Try turing off SEF in the main joomla configuration.

refresh the page and try agian?

are you using

```
JRoute:_('index.php') or JRoute:_('index.php?option=com_users')
```

in your form action?

the link just looks wrong.

Is that the default registration form ? there shouldnt be any task in the url.